# letrec in scheme with double brackets?

Tags: scheme

I am failing to understand the ribbon01 code, confused with the brackets. Can somebody explain it to me I am new to scheme

```
(define ribbon01
  (lambda (lat)
    ((letrec
         ((di (lambda (lat)
                (display lat))))
       di) (cdr lat))))

(define ribbon02
  (lambda (lat)
    (letrec (( di (lambda (lat)
                  (display lat))))
    (di (cdr lat)))))
```

The ribbon02 is very easy to understand as there are 2 statements in letrec, declaration of di and then call to di.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the double brackets in (1) and the returned value in (2):

```
(define ribbon01
  (lambda (lat)
    ((letrec ; (1)
         ((di (lambda (lat)
                (display lat))))
       di)   ; (2)
     (cdr lat))))
```

What's happenning is that we're returning `di` in (2) and then we *apply* it in (1) passing as parameter `(cdr lat)` - remember, a pair of `()` *applies* the value passed as a function, and in this case that value is `di`. It's the same as `ribbon02`, except that the function application in `ribbon01` occurs *outside* `letrec`.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to wrap an expression in extra parenthesis is if you want to apply it as a procedure.

```
(define ribbon01
  (lambda (lat)
    ((letrec ((di (lambda (lat)
                    (display lat))))
       di)
     (cdr lat))))
```

Now the only variable in the `letrec` that is made is `di` and it is a procedure of one argument. Then in the body of the `letrec` `di` is evaluated, thus the result of the whole `letrec` is a procedure. Since `di` isn't used inside the lambda we can simplify the whole `letrec` with the lambda form.

```
(define ribbon01
  (lambda (lat)
    ((lambda (lat) (display lat)) (cdr lat))))
```

Now the lambda there is just using the one argument and supply `display` thus. we can substitute that as well:

```
(define ribbon01
  (lambda (lat)
    (display (cdr lat))))
```

So if you imagine you evaluate `(ribbon01 '(1 2 3 4))` you know the `cdr` would amount to `(2 3 4)` and that is what is displayed.

The `ribbon02` doesn't evaluate the procedure back and then call it but apply it from within the `letrec`. It's perhaps a more common way to use `letrec` but the result is the same. Again you replace `di` with what it represents:

```
(define ribbon02
  (lambda (lat)
    ((lambda (lat) (display lat)) (cdr lat))))
```

And you see that you are at the same spot as with `ribbon01` and can do the same reductions from there.

So if you have an expression `e` and put parentheses around it `(e something)` you know the expression `e` needs to evaluate to a procedure and that something is to become it's one argument.

It is nothing different than `(+ 1 2)` since `+` is also an expression that becomes a procedure and since it has extra parentheses around it it is being applied just as with your `letrec`. Nothing different at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually simplified the function before posting it on this forum. Thank you very much again for your time